# uislider value changes when I click on programmatically created uilabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uislider

I have a uislider (*fontSizeSlider) which changes programmatically created uilabel's text size. When I have like 2 to 5 programmatically created labels in my view with different text size, I want the UISlider position to be changed to its corresponding value(1-50 is the min and max size of uislider) for each label when touched(touchesbegan).

Such that, if label1 textsize is 10 and label2 textsize is 20 and label5 textsize is 50(Note: the text size was change using the uislider). When I click(touch) label1 or label2 or label5, I want the uislider to show the corresponding values.(What i mean is that the uislider bar should move to 10 if label1 is selected and to 20 when label2 is selected and so on.)

Here is my sample code which i tried on touchesbegan,

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 touch=[touches anyObject];
 CGPoint fontSliderLocation = [touch locationInView:fontSizeSlider];
        NSLog(@"Location of x %f and Location of y %f", fontSliderLocation.x, fontSliderLocation.y);
```

This is not the full code, I just put it here to make some sense. Using the above code I'm able to get the x and y location of the touched label. But, how do i get the text size of the label and be able to change the uislider value when i click/touch on any of the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i get the text size of the label and be able to change the
>   uislider value when i click/touch on any of the labels.

You can get the **fontsize** by this:

```
NSString *fontName=self.label.font.fontName;
CGFloat fontSize=self.label.font.pointSize;
```

And on this delegate :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
    UITouch *touch=[touches <object>];
    if(touch.view.tag == <your Tag>){
       slider.value=<the value you want>;
    }
    else...
 }
```

**Edit:** For knowing the color use:

```
UIColor *color=self.textField.textColor;
CGFloat r,g,b,a;
[color getRed:&r green:&g blue: &b alpha: &a];
NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f",r, g, b);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked exactly like I wanted it too. Another quick question, is there a way to get the label color and assign it UiColorSlider?

Comment: I Tried, const CGFloat *rgba = CGColorGetComponents([_label textColor].CGColor);
        r=rgba[0];
        g=rgba[1]; //Green always returns 1   
        b=rgba[2];  Red and Blue returns the assigned color from the label to the sliders, but green always returns 1.

Comment: Then i dont have answer, I was never an ios developer nor am I. And in my XCodes it says something ios6.1 or so... :(

Comment: Np. Thanks for your time in trying to help me out with the answer.

Comment: can i use your CGColor etc in my XCode4.6?

Comment: Yeah you can. I was only taking about the ios version.

Answer (score 0):

you can get font name and font size of `UILable` like above and also change the value of slider with its `setValue` method like bellow...

```
[yourSlider setValue:yourFloatValue];
```